# Getting "Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment" when attempting to create a new Maven project in VSCode

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, java-home

I'm attempting to generate a Maven project via `VSCode`'s **Maven for Java** extension.

Here's my issue: After I click "Create new Maven Project" in the Explorer, choose the quickstart option, and choose the folder I want to work in, I am given an error in terminal which reads as follows:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Currently, my `JAVA_HOME` system variable is set as `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_271`.

Any suggestions for how to make this error go away? I'm not sure if it matters, but my `JDK` is installed on my C drive and I am attempting to create a project on my M drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try typing `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version` in a command line? What's the result?

Comment: Hey @LukasWerner- I just did that and got "The system cannot find the path specified.". Thoughts?

Answer (score 9):

**1.Add java to PATH:**

> Control Panel-> System-> Advanced system settings-> Environment
> Variables:
>
> Under User variables, Choose Path, click New:
>
> Copy the path of the JDK bin directory. [image]
>
> Open Command Prompt, and run `java --version`. If there's no error
> shown and you get the right jdk information, turn to the next step;

**2.Install `Java Extension Pack` in VS Code;**

**3.Press Ctrl+Shift+P to open Command Platte and choose `Java: Configure Java Runtime`:**

> Turn to **Java Tooling Runtime** and select your installed jdk, JDK
> for Language Server is equivalent to java.home: [image]

Then reload VS Code to make change effective.

Comment: Hey Molly, thanks for the response.

However, I am afraid that this did not solve my issue. I followed all of the steps you listed but still am confronted with the same issue. I'm not sure if this might be impacting anything, but I have two versions of Java installed: Java 11 via AdoptOpenJDK and Java 8 via Oracle. I'm only given the option of Java 11 for the language server.

Comment: I just got it to work with help from your solution. After I set both java 11/bin as both a Path user variable and a system variable under "JAVA_HOME" the extension started working.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this problem was setting both a user Path variable and a new system variable "JAVA_HOME" specifically to the address of the bin folder of my Java 11 installation.

In my case the path looked like this:
`C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.8.10-hotspot\bin`

I have a hunch that my issue may have related to the fact that I have two JDKs installed- one for Java 8 and one for Java 11- but I'm not sure.

Thank you to those who helped!

Comment: JAVA_HOME must not direct to bin folder but the one above. Anything else is correct. From your reply above I assume you haven't set this environment variable correctly. Glad it works now

Comment: yay!!!! you are today's hero :)

Comment: setting it as a new system variable was enough for me

Answer (score 3):

I have manage to configure this entirely through Visual Studio Code. Using the reference for the Maven extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-maven

I set my Java home path in Visual Studio Code, like this (inside of `settings.json`):

```json
"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-9.0.4"
```

And then you can enable Maven to use the same path with the settings below:

```json
"maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am developing with  Visual Studio Code Remote - SSH , v0.102.0.

There you have to set for the Java Extension Pack, v0.25.13, in your settings.json file :

```
   "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "whateverdirjavaisinstalled",
```

which takes care of JAVA_HOME for the Java Extension.  But for the Maven for Java Extension, also from Microsoft, v0.42.0, you need additionally - redundantly to have:

```
      "java.home": "whateverdirjavaisinstalled",
       "maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true,
```

The java.home entry will be marked as being deprecated. Also note the additional maven.terminal entry. A slight mess to say the least, ok considering the versions....

So you will have a settings.json like the following:

```
 "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "whateverdirjavaisinstalled",
 "java.home": "whateverdirjavaisinstalled",
 "maven.terminal.useJavaHome": true,
```

I found it practical to the settings.json within the remote project in the .vscode folder.

At least that is what worked for me