# Problem in creating a project using java extension package in visual studio code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, project

When I try to create a project in visual studio code using the downloaded Java extension package it gives me the following error:

Error: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to find out where you have installed the Java SDK and then set the environment variable in your operating system accordingly. Here a [guide for Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html). On Linux add `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/java` in your `.profile` (Ubuntu) or `.bash_profile` on other distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Java installed path to your machine's environmental variables.

Follow this tutorial - [How to set JAVA_HOME on Windows 10?](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Java Extension Pack in VS code and add the jdk path?
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331242/getting-error-java-home-not-found-in-your-environment-when-attempting-to-crea) question.